# mapping function in matlab / octave like mapcar in LISP

Tags: matlab, octave, higher-order-functions

I am looking to find mapping functions in matlab. So here is the example I'm thinking of:

```
kvec = 0:1:16
kvec =

 0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16
```

Now I wish to produce a second vector called hvec which essentially computes 10 ^ -k for each value in the kvec.

Is there an elegant way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrayfun`, `cellfun`, `spfun`, `structfun` and `bsxfun` are some useful mapping functions in MATLAB.

For example using `arrayfun` `hvec` would be computed this way:

```
hvec = arrayfun(@(x) 10^-x, kvec)
```

This syntax is obviously longer than using array power `.^`, but as `arrayfun` is a **mapping function** it works for any given function, whereas there are only a few **array functions** available (whose operators' first character is `.` such as `.^`, `.*` etc.).

Comment: Many thanks for the response. How about performance considerations?

Comment: At least `arrayfun`, `cellfun`, `spfun` and `structfun` are also available in GNU Octave (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Function-Application.html)).

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you need is

```
kvec = 0:1:16;
hvec = 10 .^ -kvec
```